# What is the relationship between res.partner and res.user in odoo13?

Tags: python, odoo

I was working in odoo12 and whenever I want to differentiate between *partner* and *user* I use following code

```
is_customer = False/True    
self.env['res.partner'].search([('customer', '=', is_customer)])
```

But now in odoo13 they removed *customer* field.
I want suggestion how to differentiate between them like above?
There is a field *employee* that is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.user` have `many2one` field to `res.partner` called `partner_id`, You can extract all partners that are users like this:

```py
   # this will extract every partner that is related to user
   partner_users = self.env['res.users'].search([]).mapped('partner_id')
```

If you want to filter partner with other field like `name` :

```py
 # first extract all ids to use them in the domain
 partner_users_ids = self.env['res.users'].search([('partner_id.name', 'ilike', some_value)]).mapped('partner_id').ids
```

Answer (score 1):

The comparison or using `customer` field working for you is more of a coincidence, because you never had partners in your Odoo without `customer` or `supplier` not being users.

But you should really use `user_ids` instead, for every version down to like Odoo 8. Because that is the one2many field using `res.users` `partner_id` field as relation which should always work.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a detailed explanation and examples in the [base: Remove customer/supplier fields on res.partner](https://gitlab.merchise.org/merchise/odoo/commit/8626257bc7b9ee772006eb17d12f56344e594f25) commit message.

**excerpt**

> > This commit allows to call `name_search` with context key
> >     `res_partner_search_mode` that can take currently two values: "customer" or
> >     "supplier".
> >
> > When ordering search results, order partners by the number of SO they have when
> >     the value is "customer" and by the number of PO if the value is "supplier".
> >
> > Top suppliers/customers are displayed above in a PO/SO partner dropdown.
> >
> > We have thought about different implementations before selecting this one